# Does the purpose of the Schengen visa application (tourism, school, or attending seminars) have an effect on the odds of success?

Tags: visas, schengen

I would like to apply for a Category C Schengen visa. Does the purpose of the visa application (tourism, summer school, or attending seminars) have an effect on the success of the visa application if the applicant is from a third-world country?

Answer (score 4):

Not per se, no.  The chance of success is primarily related to the quality of the application.  Visa applications are not a weighted game of chance.  Visa statistics say more about the people who choose to apply for a visa than they do about the decision process.

For example, consider country A where 90% of Schengen tourist applications are successful, and country B where the figure is 60%.  Then consider two people, Alice and Bob, who are both bankers making €10,000 a month.  Alice is from country A and Bob is from country B.  Is Alice's chance of getting a visa 90%?  No.  Is Bob's 60%?  No.  Is Alice's greater than Bob's?  No.  They are both going to get the visa.

Now consider two more people, also from countries A and B, who both drive taxis and make €300 a month.  Does one of them have a better chance to get a tourist visa than the other?  No.  Neither of them will get it.

The difference between country A and country B is that in country A, fewer people who can't afford to travel to Europe are submitting visa applications, and fewer people whose applications would be unsuccessful for other reasons are submitting visa applications.  That could be for any of a number of reasons.  But it does not affect the outcome of any individual application.